# How to subtract dates from each other 

Tags: date, text, groovy, format, relative-time-span

I am using Groovy.  I have parsed a textfile whose lines contain information, including dates.  I now have just the dates, for example:

```
08:13:16,121
09:32:42,102
10:43:47,153
```

I want to compare the deltas between these values; how can I do this?  i.e, I want to subtract the first from the second, and compare that value to the difference between the third and the second.  I will save the largest value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your times are in a file `times.txt`, you can do this:

```
def parseDate = { str -> new Date().parse( 'H:m:s,S', str ) }

def prevDate = null
def deltas = []

use( groovy.time.TimeCategory ) {
  new File( 'times.txt' ).eachLine { line ->
    if( line ) {
      if( !prevDate ) {
        prevDate = parseDate( line )
      }
      else {
        def nextDate = parseDate( line )
        deltas << nextDate - prevDate
        prevDate = nextDate
      }
    }
  }
}
println deltas
println( deltas.max { it.toMilliseconds() } )
```

Which will print:

```
[1 hours, 19 minutes, 25.981 seconds, 1 hours, 11 minutes, 5.051 seconds]
1 hours, 19 minutes, 25.981 seconds
```

Comment: Is there a way to print the 5 largest deltas?

Comment: @blaughli try `deltas.sort { -it.toMilliseconds() }.take( 5 )` (groovy 1.8.3+) or `deltas.sort { -it.toMilliseconds() }[0..4]` (Groovy 1.8.2 or less)

Comment: Is there a way for me to know the index of those 5 max values in the collection?

Comment: @blaughli this seems like a question that never ends ;-) How about: `println( [deltas,0..<deltas.size()].transpose().sort { -it[0].toMilliseconds() }.take( 5 ) )`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [TimeCategory](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html) to add methods for time differences to date classes:

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

use(TimeCategory) {
    println date1 - date2
}
```

Subtracting one date from another will result in a [TimeDuration](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/TimeDuration.html) object.