# Are higher order functions on collections guaranteed to be executed sequentially?

Tags: collections, groovy, higher-order-functions

In another question, a user suggested to write code like to that:

```
def list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
def i = 0; 
assert list.collect { [i++] } == [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Such code is, in other languages, considered bad practice because the content of collect changes the state of it's context (here it changes the value of `i`). In other words, the closure has side-effects.

Such higher order functions should be able to run the closure in parallel, and assemble it in a new list again. If the processing in the closure are long, CPU intensive operations, it may be worth executing them in separate threads. It would be easy to change `collect` to use an [`ExecutorCompletionService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) to achieve that, but it would break the above code.

Another example of a problem is if, for some reason, `collect` browse the collection in, say, reverse order, in which case the result would be `[3, 2, 1, 0]`. Note that in this case, the list have not been reverted, 0 is really the result of applying the closure to 'd'!

Interestingly, these functions are documented with "*Iterates through this collection*" in [Collection's JavaDoc](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html), which suggests the iteration is sequential.

**Does the groovy specification explicitly defines the order of execution in higher order functions like `collect` or `each`**? Is the above code broken, or is it OK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't like explicit external variables being relied upon in my closures for the reasons you give above.

Indeed, the less variables I have to define, the happier I am ;-)

For the possibly parallel things as well, always code with a view to wrapping it with some level of [GPars loveliness](http://gpars.codehaus.org/) should it prove too much for a single thread to handle.  For this, as you say, you want as little mutability as possible and to try and completely avoid side-effects (such as the external counter pattern above)

As for the question itself, if we take `collect` as an example function, and examine [the source code](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L1976), we can see that given an `Object` ([`Collection`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/GROOVY_1_8_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L2018) and [`Map`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/GROOVY_1_8_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L2159) are done in a similar way with slight differences as to how the Iterator is referenced) it iterates along `InvokerHelper.asIterator(self)`, adding the result of each closure call to the resultant list.

`InvokerHelper.asIterator` (again [source is here](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/InvokerHelper.java#L490)) basically calls the `iterator()` method on the Object passed in.

So for [Lists](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#iterator%28%29), etc it will iterate down the objects in the order defined by the iterator.

It is therefore possible to compose your own class which follows the [Iterable interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) design (doesn't need to implement `Iterable` though, thanks to duck-typing), and define how the collection will be iterated.

I think by asking about the Groovy specification though, this answer might not be what you want, but I don't think there is an answer.  Groovy has never really had a 'complete' specification (indeed this is point about groovy that [some people dislike](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/cayhorstmann/archive/2011/06/27/praise-language-specs)).

Comment: Updated my answer to add links to differences between `Collections`, `Lists`, and `Objects` that happen to have an `iterator()` method ;-)

Comment: Did you post a link to the source code in the hope that people would notice your name in the author tags? Nobody like a show-off (worked on me, though).

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I can expect a better answer.

Comment: @Antoine you could try the groovy-user mailing list

Comment: @Don hehe..very far down the list of authors though ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think keeping the functions passed `collect` or `findAll` side-effect free is a good idea in general, not only for keeping the complexity low but making the code more parallel-friendly in case parallel execution is needed in the future.

But in the case of `each` there is not much point in keeping the function side-effect free, as it wouldn't do anything (in fact the sole purpose of this method is to replace act as a for-each loop). The [Groovy's documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1015-Collections) have some examples of using `each` (and its variants, `eachWithIndex` and `reverseEach`) that require an execution order to be defined.

Now, from a pragmatic point of view, I think it can sometimes be OK to use functions with some side effects in methods like `collect`. For example, to transform a list in `[index, value]` pairs a `transpose` and range [can be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087873/how-to-know-the-indices-of-values-in-collection/8087916#8087916)

```
def list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
def enumerated = [0..<list.size(), list].transpose()
assert enumerated == [[0,'a'], [1,'b'], [2,'c']]
```

Or even an `inject`

```
def enumerated = list.inject([]) { acc, val -> acc << [acc.size(), val] }
```

But a `collect` and a counter does the trick too and I think the result is the most readable:

```
def n = 0, enumerated = list.collect{ [n++, it] }
```

Now, this example wouldn't make sense if Groovy provided a`collect` and similar methods with a index-value-param function (see [Jira issue](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-3797)), but it kinda shows that sometimes practicality beats purity IMO :)